# What is difference between return action & dispatch an action in NGRX effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, angular14

I would like to know which code is better and more optimized when handling complex logic in an NgRx effect. Most of the time, we break the effect logic into pieces of action. In this case, should we use **dispatch action** or **return action**? Which one is the better option? And how does the **dispatch flag** help in an effect?

Answer (score 0):

In NgRx, there is a distinction between returning an action and dispatching an action.

`1. Returning an action:`
Returning an action from an effect means that the effect itself emits an action as its result. When an effect returns an action, it means that the effect is responsible for triggering the next action in the flow. The returned action will be dispatched automatically by the NgRx framework.

Here's an example of returning an action from an effect:

```js
@Injectable()
export class YourEffects {
  yourEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(YourActionTypes.YOUR_TRIGGERING_ACTION),
      map((action: YourAction) => {
        // Perform your asynchronous logic here

       // Dispatch a new action only within this effect
        return new YourNextAction();
       //OR        
        return { type: YourActionTypes.YOUR_EFFECT_ACTION, payload: { /* payload data */ } };
      }),
      { dispatch: false } // Prevent the effect from dispatching the action
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

In this example, `YourNextAction` is the action that will be returned by the effect and automatically dispatched.

If you set `dispatch` to `false` in the effect and use `this.store.dispatch(action)` instead of returning an action, it will affect the behavior of the effect and the flow of actions in your NgRx application.

2. `dispatch: false`:
   Setting `dispatch` to `false` in the effect configuration means that the effect will not automatically dispatch the action to the store. This is useful when you want to perform side effects or handle the action within the effect without triggering further actions or state updates.
3. `this.store.dispatch(action)`:
   If you use `this.store.dispatch(action)` instead of returning an action from the effect, it means you are manually dispatching the action to the store. This will trigger the normal NgRx flow, where the action will be processed by reducers and potentially result in state updates.

Here's an example to illustrate the difference:

```js
yourEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(YourActionTypes.YOUR_TRIGGERING_ACTION),
    map((action: YourAction) => {
      // Perform your asynchronous logic here

      // Manually dispatch the action to the store
      this.store.dispatch(new YourNextAction());
    }),
    { dispatch: false } // Set dispatch to false to prevent automatic dispatch
  )
);
```

In this example, when `YourActionTypes.YOUR_TRIGGERING_ACTION` is dispatched, the effect will be triggered. It performs its asynchronous logic and then manually dispatches `YourNextAction` using `this.store.dispatch()`. The `{ dispatch: false }` option ensures that the effect itself does not dispatch any action automatically.

By using `this.store.dispatch(action)`, the action will follow the standard NgRx flow. It will go through the registered reducers, potentially causing state updates, triggering additional effects, and any other NgRx middleware you have configured.

It's important to consider the implications of using `this.store.dispatch(action)` within an effect instead of returning an action. Be mindful of the resulting action flow and whether it aligns with your intended application behavior and state management requirements.